# redirection problem with .htaccess that removes .php and adds trailing slash

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

**starting point:**

i am using the following code in my .htaccess. the code removes .php extension and adds a trailing slash at the end.

```
Options -Indexes
Options -Multiviews

CheckSpelling off

RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /


# forward always without www and with https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]



# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=301,L]


# Add a trailing slash at the end
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]


# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

example: "example.com/existing_php_file.php" becomes "example.com/existing_php_file/"

this works perfectly.

the following variants are also working as expected:

1. "example.com/existing_folder/not_existing_file_or_folder" gives a 404 message
2. "example.com/not_existing_file_or_folder" gives a 404 message

**problem:**

I got a redirection errors when someone inputs the following:

1. example.com/existing_php_file_without_extension/not_existing_file_or_folder
2. example.com/existing_folder/existing_php_file_without_extension/not_existing_file_or_folder

**own analysis:**

I checked "example.com/existing_folder/existing_php_file_without_extension/not_existing_file_or_folder"  with http://www.redirect-checker.org/index.php.

I seems the code in .htaccess adds a "/" and then ".php/" and then a "/" again and so on.

example.com/existing_folder/existing_php_file_without_extension/not_existing_file_or_folder 301 Moved Permanently example.com/existing_folder/existing_php_file_without_extension/not_existing_file_or_folder/ 301 Moved Permanently example.com/existing_folder/existing_php_file_without_extension/not_existing_file_or_folder.php/ 301 Moved Permanently example.com/existing_folder/existing_php_file_without_extension/not_existing_file_or_folder/ 301 Moved Permanently

I redirect-checker counts 19 redirects like the ones above. which makes safari and chrome (and I think also other browsers) send an error that there are to many redirects (which is true).

**question:**

any ideas how to modify the .htacces to get 404 errors instead of the redirect errors?

Comment: my test was with -MultiViews already. I added the rest of my .htaccess in my previous post.

Comment: Try to replace `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f` with `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f`

Comment: that does the trick. thanks a lot @anubhava

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On some Apache servers `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` can misbehave. Better to replace that with this rule to internally ad `.php`:

```
# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```